# How to properly create a list subclass that returns a list generated from file in python?

Tags: python, list, inheritance, return, subclassing

I am running into some problems with subclassing.

I need to create a class that inherits list properties but I need the returned list (**self.tiles_pool**) to be one that is created when the class is constructed. The list is generated by an external CSV file. I tried creating the class without inheritance but quickly realized there was no way to return my list without creating a separate method to do so. But I need the instance of the class to be a list object (i.e. print the generated list when I print the object). The class is for creating a Tile Pool like the bag of letter tiles in scrabble.

If there is some way of returning my list (**self.tiles_pool**) **without inheritance** and **without using user defined methods** that would be better.

Here is my code so far:

```
import csv
import random


class TilePool(list):
    def __init__(self):
        list.__init__(self)

        # Open csv file
        with open("tiles.csv") as f:
            # Read csv into list of lists of each lines values
            tiles_csv = csv.reader(f, delimiter=",")

            # Convert the list into a tile pool
            self.tiles_pool = [(line[0], line[1])
                               for line in tiles_csv if len(line[0]) == 1
                               for x in xrange(int(line[2]))]

            del tiles_csv

    def pop(self, tile_count=None):
        assert len(self.tiles_pool) > 0, "# Tile Pool is empty"

        if tile_count is None:
            tile_count = 7

        assert tile_count in xrange(1, 8), "# Tile Count must be between 1 and 7"

        new_tiles = []
        counter = 1
        while len(self.tiles_pool) > 0 and counter <= tile_count:
            rand_choice = random.choice(self.tiles_pool)  # Get a random tile
            new_tiles.append(rand_choice)  # Add it to new_tiles list
            self.tiles_pool.remove(rand_choice)  # Delete it from pool

            counter += 1

        return new_tiles

    def view_pool(self):
        if len(self.tiles_pool) == 0:
            print("# Tile Pool is empty")

        else:
            for tile in self.tiles_pool:
                print("{letter}: {score}".format(letter=tile[0], score=tile[1]))

            print len(self.tiles_pool)
```

I understand that this implementation may seem strange and I could probably just put this in a function but I am under instruction to make it a class. Any help or advice would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why subclass `list` if you don't use it? `self` is the list you want, there is no need to create a `tiles_pool`. Since lists can be initialized with a sequence, delay parent `__init__` until you can feed it the csv. Your code does some things I don't understand such as duplicating tiles `line[2]` times, but I figure you know what you are doing there.

In this sample, I remove `tiles_pool` in favor of using `self` and do a few other tweaks like using the "truthiness" of lists (`bool([1]) is True` while `bool([]) is False`) instead of using `len` but it should work the same as the original.

```
import csv
import random


class TilePool(list):
    def __init__(self):
        with open("tiles.csv") as f:
            tiles_csv = csv.reader(f, delimiter=",")
            list.__init__(self, (line[0:2]
                           for line in tiles_csv if len(line[0]) == 1
                           for x in xrange(int(line[2]))))


    def pop(self, tile_count=None):
        # non-empty list is truthy
        assert self, "# Tile Pool is empty"

        if tile_count is None:
            tile_count = 7

        assert tile_count in range(1, 8), "# Tile Count must be between 1 and 7"

        new_tiles = []
        counter = 1
        while self and counter <= tile_count:
            rand_choice = random.choice(self)  # Get a random tile
            new_tiles.append(rand_choice)  # Add it to new_tiles list
            self.remove(rand_choice)  # Delete it from pool
            counter += 1
        return new_tiles

    def view_pool(self):
        if not self:
            print("# Tile Pool is empty")
        else:
            for tile in self:
                print("{letter}: {score}".format(letter=tile[0], score=tile[1]))
            print len(self)

t = TilePool()
t.pop(3)
t.view_pool()
```

Comment: Oh I see! Ok. Thank you this is exactly what I needed. I tried searching for how to do this and got close to something like the `list.__init__` part. I haven't worked much with inheritance so i wasn't sure what it meant.

Comment: Yeah, it can be puzzling at first. You implemented a "has a" relationship (my object has a list so I need to write my own accessors) and this is a "is a" relationship (my object is a list so the existing methods work on it).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid inheritance and user-defined methods, I'd leverage python's [magic](http://www.rafekettler.com/magicmethods.html) methods to do so.